# Hartshorne Lemma III.7.4 Proof

Tags: algebraic-geometry, proof-explanation, schemes

I have a question about an argument used in the proof on Lemma 7.4 (Chap. III) from Hartshorne's "Algebraic Geometry":

[image]

Rmk:We work with the setting from 7.3: So $X $ is projective, therefore closed subscheme of $P:= \mathbb{P}^N_k$ of codimension $r$.

In the proof - using the observation that the $\mathscr{J}^i=\mathscr{Hom}_P(O_V,\mathscr{I}^i) $ are injective - we conclude that the complex $\mathscr{J}^{\bullet}$ splits to $\mathscr{J}^{\bullet}=\mathscr{J}^{\bullet}_1 \oplus \mathscr{J}^{\bullet}_2$ where

-$\mathscr{J}^{\bullet}_1$ is in degrees $0 \le i \le r$ (non zero) and is exact (so $h^i(\mathscr{J}^{\bullet}_1)=0$ for $0 \le i \le r$

-$\mathscr{J}^{\bullet}_2$  is in degrees $i \ge r$ (non zero)

Then we can conclude (unsure why) that $$\omega^{\circ}_X = ker(d^r:\mathscr{J}^{r}_2 \to \mathscr{J}^{r+1}_2)$$

I think that this is because by definition $\omega^{\circ}_X = \mathscr{Ext}^r _P(O_X, \omega_P)$. Then following the argumentation above we get $\mathscr{Ext}^r _P(O_X, \omega_P)=h^i(Hom_X(O_X,\mathscr{J}^{\bullet}) = h^i(\mathscr{J}^{\bullet}) $ since $Hom_X(O_X,\mathscr{J}^{\bullet}) \cong \mathscr{J}^{\bullet}$. Is this a correct argument?

The QUESTION is that I don't understand why this implies

$$Hom_X(\mathcal{F},\omega^{\circ}_X)=  Ext^r _P(\mathcal{F}, \omega_P)$$?

My ideas:

By above & definition of cohomology we know $$Ext^r _P(\mathcal{F}, \omega_P)=h^r(Hom_X(\mathcal{F}, \mathscr{J}^{\bullet}))= \frac{ker(\bar{d}^r: Hom_X(\mathcal{F}, \mathscr{J}^{r}_1 \oplus \mathscr{J}^{r}_2) \to Hom_X(\mathcal{F}, \mathscr{J}^{r+1}_2))}{im(\bar{d}^{r-1}: Hom_X(\mathcal{F}, \mathscr{J}^{r-1}_1)  \to Hom_X(\mathcal{F}, \mathscr{J}^{r}_1 \oplus \mathscr{J}^{r}_2))}$$

But why does the last expression coinside with $Hom_X(\mathcal{F},ker(d^r:\mathscr{J}^{r}_2 \to \mathscr{J}^{r+1}_2))$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you should know that the way Hartshorne sets up the decomposition $J=J_1\oplus J_2$, there are no nonzero maps from any term of $J_1$ to any term of $J_2$ or vice-versa. So the kernels and cokernels of this sequence are just the direct sums of the kernels and cokernels from the complexes $J_1$ and $J_2$, and the homology of $J$ is just the direct sum of homologies from $J_1$ and $J_2$. Since $J_1$ is exact, that means it contributes nothing to the homology at any step, and since $J_2^i$ is zero for $i<r$, that means the homology at the $r^{th}$ term is just $\ker(J_2^{r}\to J_2^{r+1})$, which explains why this is isomorphic to $\omega_X^\circ$.

Next, you should observe that $J_1$ being a split exact sequence of injective objects means that it's isomorphic to a direct sum of complexes of the form $0\to A \stackrel{id}{\to} A \to 0$ up to a shift in degree with $A$ injective. So $\operatorname{Hom}(F,J_1)$ can be decomposed as a direct sum of complexes of the form $0\to\operatorname{Hom}(F,A)\stackrel{id}{\to} \operatorname{Hom}(F,A)\to 0$ up to shifts in degree, and this means it has trivial homology. So we get that the complexes $\operatorname{Hom}^\bullet(F,J)=\operatorname{Hom}^\bullet(F,J_1\oplus J_2) = \operatorname{Hom}^\bullet(F,J_1)\oplus \operatorname{Hom}^\bullet(F,J_2)$ and $\operatorname{Hom}^\bullet(F,J_2)$ have equal homology. But the first computes $\operatorname{Ext}^\bullet_P(F,\omega_P)$ while the second (after a grading shift by $r$) computes $\operatorname{Ext}^\bullet_X(F,\omega_X^\circ)$ since the shifted $J_2$ is an injective resolution of $\omega_X^\circ$ by the work we did in the first paragraph. Then $\operatorname{Ext}^0_X(F,\omega_X^\circ)=\operatorname{Hom}_X(F,\omega_X^\circ)$ and we're done.

Comment: The point that $J_1^{\bullet}$ is a split exact sequence irritates me. What is the argument that $J_1^{\bullet}$ has this property? If I understood you correctly that it says that every $d_1^k: J_1 ^k \cong A_k \oplus B_k \to B_k \oplus C_k \cong J_1 ^{k+1}$ has the shape 

$$\left(\begin{matrix} 0 & id_{B_k} \\ 0 & 0 \end{matrix}\right)$$

right?

But what is here the main ingredient which garantees that $J_1^{\bullet}$ has this shape? It cannot be only the exactness and injectivity.

Comment: Since otherwise - as you pointed out - the property that $J_1^{\bullet}$ is a split exact sequence would lead to the conclusion that after applying any left exact functor $F$ (in our example $F=Hom(A,-)$) the resulting sequence $F(J_1^{\bullet})$ would stay exact this would imply that the derived functor $R^iF$ is always zero for every object $N$ with exact injective resolution $N \to I^{\bullet}$.

Comment: $J_1$ split exact is consequence of the fact that $J_1$ consists of injective objects and is exact. Consider $0\to J_1^0\to J_1^1\to \operatorname{im}(J_1^1\to J_1^2)\to 0$. This is exact and $J_1^0$ is injective, so it splits. So $J_1^1=J_1^0\oplus \tilde{J}_1^1$, and as every direct summand of an injective module is injective, we may split off the $0\to J_1^0\to J_1^0\to 0$ and proceed (until we get to the $r^{th}$ step where things are slightly different). Your second comment is incorrect: $I^\bullet$ is not exact, it has zeroth homology $N$, so the same trick does not work.